# SQL CASE WHEN THEN logics of calculating the types of a column

Tags: sql, group-by, case

Have a tableA like this:

[image]

I wanna receive a tableИ like this (group by startTime and endTime, count of Severity in cnt column and count of every type of Severity in a distinct column):

[image]

The simple count (cnt column) works fine. But with the other I tired CASE WHEN THEN logics and it seems not working (line 10 for example). Can you please assist me with SQL query in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *conditional* aggregation :

```
select starttime, endtime, count(*),
       sum(case when severity = 'low' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when severity = 'med' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when severity = 'high' then 1 else 0 end)
from table t
group by starttime, endtime;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below query: with case when

```
select starttime, endtime, count(severity) as cnt, count(case when severity='LOW' then 1 end) cnt_low,count(case when severity='MED' then 1 end) cnt_med,count(case when severity='HIGH' then 1 end) as cnt_high
from tablename
group by starttime, endtime
```

Answer (score 2):

use case when and aggregate function `sum`

```
select startTime , endTime,count(*) as Cnt,
sum( case when Severity='MED' then 1 else 0 end) as cntMed,
sum( case when Severity='LOW' then 1 else 0 end) as cntLow,
sum( case when Severity='HIGH' then 1 else 0 end) as cntHIGH from yourtable
group by startTime , endTime
```